# Search page design with logical operators

Tags: design, search, application-design, ui, product-design

I have a page that displays a set of records. The page has filter section to search records.
[image]

currently the logical operator AND is applied between all the filter conditions. Now the requirement for including the OR operation has arisen. The user suggested to add a dropdown with AND,OR options next to Value dropdown. But the problem is operator precedence. If I am going to make the page to look like the image below, the user is definitely going to find it confusing and I am also not sure how to resolve this search.  [image]

Please suggest me how I could make this UI to let the user select the operator precedence easily.

Comment: Reminds me on http://www.usabilitycounts.com/2012/01/31/simplicity-google-apple-and-your-company/  Though sophisticated solutions like the one suggested by @CandiedOrange exist, I wonder if the possibility of simply entering a query string in a text box would not be more usable in the end.

Comment: :) true indeed. The product has been designed this way and sadly my company does not want to invest much in rewriting this in a textbox way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a query builder to me. In code you'd use parentheses to override operator precedence but this is a GUI. Here's how others have solved it:

> [image]
>
> [querybuilder.js.org](http://querybuilder.js.org/)

Here groups are used to control precedence. Grouping is shown with indenting, boxes, and tree lines. I think this is better than a column that lets you chose parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Depending whether you plan to support arbitrary Boolean expressions, I would choose one of the following:

- If you plan to make any logical expression possible, just make a single query box with support for syntax such as: `word1 AND word2 OR (word3 AND NOT word4) ...`. If your users are capable of building queries of this complexity, they will also be able to grasp the query syntax. In my experience, typing up a search expression like this is much more convenient than clicking and moving around text boxes in a complex layout.
- If you only want to support basic queries with AND and OR operators, make two sets of words: and-words and or-words, then fix the actually executed expression to be: `and_word_1 AND and_word_2 AND ... OR (or_word_1 OR ord_word_2 OR ...)`. You can also add not-words (applied after and- and or-words). This actually handles almost all cases needed in practice and is quite easy to understand for the users.